# doctrine many to one

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have to Entity User and Address. My task is to relationship them many-to-one with the help of Doctrine. Methode get Address return only id of the Address and nothing else 
**Class User**

```
class User{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var Address
 * @ORM\@ManyToOne(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\Address", mappedBy="user")
 */
protected $addressData;


/**
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Address
 */
protected function getAddress(){
    return $this->addressData;
}
```

and **Class Address**

```
class Address{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

 /**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="addressData")
 * JoinColumn(name="address",referencedColumnName = "id")
 */
protected $users;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

I cant to relationship them

Comment: @ scoolnico get User from DB that will combine user.info+address.info in one object

Comment: After a query in User (e.g: `$user = $em->findById('1');`) the object must contains what you need if your mapping is correct: For example: `$city = $user->getAddress()->getCity();`

Answer (score 0):

With your implementation, one Address can have many User.
If you want the inverse, inverse your mapping and regenerate your entities.

In every cases, don't forget to do :

```
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities
```

Then, when you have all getters and setters in your entity :

If you want add an address to your user in controller action, just do :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

$user = new User();   // Create a new user
$em->persist($user); // P1ersist new user

$address = new Address() // Create a new address
$address->addUser($user); // Add address to newly created user;
$em->persist($address); // Persist the newly created address

$em->flush(); // Flush all in DB
```

And for retrieve users from an address :

```
$address->getUsers();
```

OR retrieve an address from user

```
$user->getAddress();
```

Hope this is what you need